# How to access codeigniter files from one directory to another different directory

Tags: apache, codeigniter, redirect, directory, root

I have XAMP installation, with htdocs in D drive. I copied Codeigniter/System folder to E drive. Now when i type http://localhost, i should able to access E:/Codeigniter/System/index.php
How can i achieve this.

Comment: Set up the apache VirtualHost and its DocumentRoot directive accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick and dirty:**
open httpd.conf (usually located in /XAMPINSTALLDIR/apache/conf), replace all "D:/xampp/htdocs" occurrences with "E:/Codeigniter" and restart your apache server. You should be able to access your codeigniter installation by this URL http://127.0.0.1

**more sensible:**
Learn about apache virtual hosts (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/vhosts/) and add a new virtual host with the appropriate document root.